# I'm trying to set up a connection to my database via the web.config file - It's just not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm developing an application with C#/ASP.NET and it needs to connect to my SQL database. I have everything set up, but I'm having a really hard time getting the web.config to work. What I'm trying to do is set up the connection string to later reference it on my code.

Here's my code:

```
  <add name="BancoMaravilhoso" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=myserver;database=beirao_teste;uid=sa;password=123123;" />

  <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I run the build it loads the page just fine. I made a function to call a stored procedure from my database on the pageload, but it's not being called. Also, I noticed that if I change the stuff within the connection string tab, like password, it doesn't throw me any errors.

OBS. I'm new to ASP.NET and whatnot

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The call to my stored procedure:

```
public class Pessoa : Base
    {
        public void CriaPessoa(string Nome, string Sexo, string Data, string Email)
        {
        using (DbConnection cn = this.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (DbCommand cmd = this.CreateCommand(cn))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "CADASTRAR";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Nome", DbType.String, Nome));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Sexo", DbType.String, Sexo));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Data", DbType.String, Data));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Email", DbType.String, Email));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AND THEN:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa();

        p1.CriaPessoa("Fulano", "M", "27/10/2012", "fulano@ciclano.com");

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a exception ? or the call just isn't being made ? if the call is not being made you need to post the code where your making the call

Comment: Why do you have two connection string ?

Comment: Can I see the code in the web form?

Comment: 1 - I'm not getting any exception. 2 - Posted the code. I have no idea why I have two, I created a project on visual studio and stuff was already there. 3 - Posted the code.

Comment: That's ok to have more connections string, the important you call the one you need by name or index.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my example.

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBC" connectionString="data source=.; database=DB; 
         integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Try this in the Web Form:

```
string CN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;
using (DbConnection cn = this.CreateConnection())
{
    using (DbCommand cmd = this.CreateCommand(CN))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "CADASTRAR";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Nome", DbType.String, Nome));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Sexo", DbType.String, Sexo));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Data", DbType.String, Data));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(this.CreateParameter("@Email", DbType.String, Email));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that Web Form part? I don't have anything like that on either of my Default files! I copied that to my Default.cs but still nothing happened :(

Comment: BTW, change database=DB with the name of your database.

Comment: Got these errors:

The best overloaded method match for 'ExercicioDotNet.Base.CreateCommand(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' has some invalid arguments  ExercicioDotNet
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' C:\Users\rodrigob\Desktop\ExercicioDotNet\ExercicioDotNet\Pessoa.cs 23 59 ExercicioDotNet

Comment: Ok, now smt start to work.  Can you comment the section Using(DbCommand..)

Answer (score 0):

in solution explorer, right click on your project and click on properties. in right hand you'll see some option.click on settings and create one new setting ,select your setting type as connection string, in 'value' column a button appears,click it and enter your connection properties in 'connection properties' window, then click on 'testconnection' and ok.created connection string is correct connection string and will add to that project's webconfig automatically